# How to obtain video details from flv file?

Tags: c#, class, shell, video, flv

I use the shellFile class to obtain video details but it works only with a few formats. The code below doesn't work with.flv or .mkv files. I don't get any errors just a null value.

```
     ShellFile shellFile = ShellFile.FromFilePath(file.FullName);
     label29.Text = (shellFile.Properties.System.Video.FrameRate.Value / 1000).ToString();
     label27.Text = shellFile.Properties.System.Video.FrameHeight.Value.ToString() + " px";
     label26.Text = shellFile.Properties.System.Video.FrameWidth.Value.ToString() + " px";
     label28.Text = shellFile.Properties.System.Video.FrameWidth.Value.ToString() + "x" + shellFile.Properties.System.Video.FrameHeight.Value.ToString() + " px";
     label9.Text = (shellFile.Properties.System.Video.TotalBitrate.Value / 1000).ToString() + " kb/s";
```

Comment: You get a null on what exactly? A shellFile?

Comment: it's a null value, the label doesn't show anything

Comment: Which variable is null exactly? Have you tried debugging? Set breakpoint at first line of relevant code and step through, watching for what shellFile contains. I highly doubt you have actuall null values on shellFile or Value fields/properties as this code would throw NullReferenceExceptions left and right.

Comment: i put a breakpoint on the label27 and the shellFile.propreties.system.video.frameheight.value = null   and the type = uint? 
this happens only happens with .mkv or .flv files